# Why does my Emulator Browser not show testpage from XAMPP?

Tags: android, xampp, emulation, mobile-website

I'm struggling to get my android emulator showing a testpage from XAMPP for mobile development. I already tried the **10.0.2.2** and also my IP Adress. Both seem to work but the mobile browser is only showing up a blank page. So i think the page is found and simply not rendered correctly. The testpage looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing an important preference in XAMPP or something like that? On my PC (Windows 7) it works just fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your browser on the emulator. First try some other browsers (like chrome, mozilla (for android), opera, etc). Because, If you are able to reach the server then you should also be able to load the page.

If that doesn't work, Try on different emulators like [genymotion](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzhq7-097UAhWJNo8KHSwxAzwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genymotion.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFe_83y8u2kkTCsdtEigYhL4Wskrw) (use 10.0.2.3 instead of 10.0.2.2), [bluestacks](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid8Z6I1N7UAhWKQY8KHfScAqkQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluestacks.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGzERPRfPol143BYS4zPBXAVfKAhA), etc.

Comment: actually genymotion was able to render it. Thanks for the help!